# How to enable mod_info in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, apache-1.3

I gone through the apache guide to enable to mod_info.

As per doc:

- To configure mod_info, add the following to your httpd.conf file.

*Location /server-info **SetHandler server-info**
/Location*

- You may wish to use mod_access inside the  directive to limit access to your server configuration information:

  *Location /server-info
  **SetHandler server-info Order deny,allow Deny from all Allow from yourcompany.com**
  Location*
- Once configured, the server information is obtained by accessing http://your.host.dom/server-info

In my case the this link is not giving any info. Http 404 NOT FOUND error

- Is there anything I need to install as mod_info.c or something ? Is there anything i need to put as AddModule or something ?
- Without virtual host I got below error : File does not exist: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/server-info [Tue Dec 11 03:39:53 2012] [error] [client 10.177.246.184] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/favicon.ico
- In Error log : File does not exist: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/example1/server-info I have 3 virtual host. One of this as default which use example1 as Docroot dir. I am not sure where this page (server-info) should be ? in case of server-status, it's working fine

Comment: What do you mean by does not give any info? What do you get, is there an error message, is there any relevant information in our apache logs ?

Comment: 404 Error Code.Not Found
The requested URL /server-info was not found on this server.

Comment: Did you restart apache after changing the configuration ?

Comment: Yes I restart the server multiple times. Is there anything I need to install as "mod_info" or include "AddModule mod_info path for mod_info.c" ? or it's default enable in Apache 2.X ?

Comment: Is there anything in your error log? That's usually a good place to start looking.

Comment: In Error log : File does not exist: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/example1/server-info I have 3 virtual host. One of this as default which use example1 as Docroot dir. I am not sure where this page (server-info) should be ? in case of server-status, it's working fine.

Comment: You're not hitting the vhost you have this configured in. Include the output of `httpd -S`  with your question.

Comment: I set <Location /server-info> SetHandler <server-info /Location> and access the http://localhost/server-info same as server-status. Is there any problem ? I think that In Apache, first Virtual Host taken as default host. So if request comes from localhost it's use first V.host.

Comment: Without virtual host I got below error : File does not exist: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/server-info
[Tue Dec 11 03:39:53 2012] [error] [client 10.177.246.184] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/favicon.ico

Answer (score 4):

I guess simply using `a2enmod  info` will work in your case.

**NOTE:** `a2enmod` is only available on Debian variants (i.e. Ubuntu, etc.). You can read more about `a2enmod` [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/a2enmod.8.html).

`a2enmod` and it's sister command `a2dismod` can be used to enable or disable apache2 modules.

#### examples

```
% a2enmod imagemap
% a2dismod mime_magic
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to make sure you have a `LoadModule info_module` statement in your httpd.conf for mod_info and you should also check that your settings are not conflicting with other mod_info-related directives below yours, in .htaccess files, or in other configuration files loaded as part of an `Include` directive. Finally, check that mod_info is actually installed. I wouldn't be surprised if it wasn't installed because the data mod_info provides is viewed as an information disclosure vulnerability by some security folks.